# Use domain to filter where users are displayed in odoo enterprise 15

Tags: python, filter, dns, odoo, inventory

I have multiple locations in inventory and I know it is location_id of stock.quant object and field type is many2one.
How can i use domain to filter users to only see a certain repository, I have tried
`[('location_id','=' ,'Stock_df')]`
but it doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Him Thanh,

You can try with below code

```
<filter name="shelf_loc" string="Shelf Locations" domain="[('location_id.name','ilike', 'Shelf')]"/>
```

Here is the sample code screenshot.
[image]

Here is the result of code.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this makes a lot of sense to me.